# what are a few main reasons that apple applications crash?

Tags: iphone, xcode

What faults in xcode could cause the app to crash? do NSLogs have anything to do with it?

I know its a vague question, but i dont know what could have cause it to crash.

I'm a beginner, and im not very experienced at programming, how does the application manage to freeze so fricking often?

There are warnings in a few places:

```
local declaration of 'webView' hides instance variable in
NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];

'dyang_s_game' may not respond to 'generateWordsArray' in
[self generateWordsArray];
```

Comment: What does your console say when it crashes? You can show it using CMD + Shift + R from XCode.

Comment: @badgerr cool thanks. i think the main problem is the freezing of the app. is iOS simulator any different than using an actual ipod to test out the code?

Comment: The iOS Simulator is *not* a substitute for actual device testing in any way, shape, or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad Memory Usage, and also coding errors, (that do not show as errors) and warnings can usualy turn out as a crash

Answer (score 1):

Treat those warnings as errors. Fix them.

Also try the static analyzer; it can show (and explain) many coding errors (in Xcode 4, use the Product->Analyze menu).

Test your code often so you can tell what just changed when a bug starts showing up. Use Xcode's git integration to track changes. That way you can easily revert to an older version to help track down exactly when a bug was introduced.

Comment: does the static analyzer thing work in xCode 3? and what is git integration? sorry im not experienced with this stuff

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous reasons why your code could be crashing.  Without posting code, it is difficult to give a lot of advice, but first you should try to resolve the errors. If you need more help with specific errors, google the error code and read how others have resolved them.  Make sure that your code initializes all the objects correctly and also deletes them.  You should read this: http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/ and make sure you understand the syntax.  It is quite possible that you are writing code that compiles but does not function the way you intended.